# ffplay / OpenFrameworks / AR Parrot Drone / TCP video

Tags: tcp, ffmpeg, video-streaming, openframeworks, ar.drone

I can get a video stream coming from AR parrot 2.0 drone by running "ffplay tcp://192.168.1.1:5555"
But I'm trying to get this video stream into OpenFrameworks.

1. is there a way to figure out how to pipe this video into OF?
2. Can I make this ffplay call directly in OF so the video is in the OF app by default?

there is no ffmpeg module for OpenFrameworks that I know of. 
Thanks

Comment: What platform are you using?  The GST based player in linux can probably do this.  You might look at https://github.com/arturoc/ofxAxisGrabber for an example of h264 video grabbing in oF.  If the video is using a frame by frame approach to encoding (like mjpeg), you might look at https://github.com/bakercp/ofxIPVideoGrabber.

Comment: It is  "h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 640x360, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc". So i'm going to try "ofAxisGrabber" as you mentioned? thanks a lot ... i'll let you know

Comment: @bakercp when trying to run the example code I'm getting the error gst.gst.h file not found and wondering if I should follow : http://blog.geoffdonaldson.com/2013/02/14/using-the-gstreamer-sdk-in-openframeworks-under-osx-10-8-mountain-lion/.  I'm using maverick and OF v8

Comment: I'd go off of this first https://github.com/arturoc/ofxGStreamer as it was written by @arturoc (they fellow who wrote the ofxAxisGrabber addon).  It is probably the same as the link you noted, but best stay close to the source of the addon!

Comment: OK cool thanks i'm trying that - I'm having quite a hard time successfully installing GStreamer on 10.9 - the header files "can't be found" and additionally trying to run "gst-launch" in terminal is returning "command not found gst-launch" so I'm trying to solve that now...thanks for the leads though! will let u kno